# C++11 constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

The new move-constructor/move-operator allows us to transfer ownership of objects and this way avoiding using (expensive) copy constructor calls. But is it possible to avoid constructing temporary objects (without using return parameters)?

Example: In the code below the constructor is called 4 times - but ideally what I would like to do is to avoid constructing any objects in the cross method. Using return parameters (for example `void cross(const Vec3 &b, Vec3& out)` would be possible, but is ugly to read. I'm interested in updating an existing variable.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vec3{
public:
    Vec3(){
        static int count = 0;
        id = count++;
        p = new float[3];
        cout << "Constructor call "<<id <<" "<<p<< " "<<this<< endl;
    }

    ~Vec3(){
        cout << "Deconstructor call "<<id << " "<<p<<" "<<this<< endl;
        delete[] p;
    }

    Vec3(Vec3&& other)
    : p(nullptr) {
        cout << "Move constructor call "<<id << " "<<p<<" "<<this<< endl;
        p = other.p;
        other.p = nullptr;
    }

    Vec3& operator=(Vec3&& other) {
        cout << "Move assignment operator call from "<<other.id<<" to "<<id << " "<<p<<" "<<this<< endl;
        if (this != &other) {
            p = other.p;
            other.p = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3 cross(const Vec3 &b){
        float ax = p[0], ay = p[1], az = p[2],
            bx = b.p[0], by = b.p[1], bz = b.p[2];
        Vec3 res;
        res.p[0] = ay * bz - az * by;
        res.p[1] = az * bx - ax * bz;
        res.p[2] = ax * by - ay * bx;
        return res;
    }

    float *p;
    int id;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Vec3 a,b,c;
    a = b.cross(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to set `nullptr` to `other.p` after moving in the constructor. Use containers or smart pointers to avoid such situation.

Comment: Re: " transfer ownership of objects" - moving has **nothing** to do with ownership. It's about the **contents** of objects, and efficiently transferring the contents when the source object will not be needed afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to return an "expression object" from `a.cross(b)`, deffering the calculation until such an object is assigned to `c`, and then in the `operator=` you actually do the calculation:

```
 struct Vec3
 {

      CrossProduct cross(const Vec3& b);

      Vec3& operator=(CrossProduct cp)
      {
          do calculation here putting result in `*this`
      }
 }
```

and add similar mechanisms for construction and so on.

This is more involved, but a number of C++ math libraries use this design pattern.

Comment: Maybe not the most simple solution, but I actually like the idea a lot :)

Comment: +1; If I am correct: There also is a way to disentangle a series of operations and concentrate them in a single function/operation ... some sort of concatenation but I don't find this one currently. It also involved such "expression objects" if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: That is correct yes, for example in matrix arithmetic there are optimized operations like `V1 = V2*M + V3`.  In order to identify the pattern you use expression objects to form a parse tree, and then execute the optimized operation all-at-once on the appropriate twigs of the tree.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that topic a little further?

Answer (score 2):

If you assign new value directly:

```
Vec3 a = b.cross(c);
```

Then it is possible that [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will take effect and there is no temporary constructed and moved later. Make sure you are compiling with optimizations. The returned value would be constructed in-place into a.

Also allocating an array of 3 floats on heap seems like a performance killer. Using C-like  array `float p[3]` or `std::array<float, 3>` should perform much better.

Comment: I wasn't clear about this - but in my case I want the cross product to update an existing variable.

Comment: Isn't RVO a compiler optimization? I was hoping for a C++ language feature to say "instead of creating temporary object just update the object the result will be assigned to"

Comment: @Mortennobel: It is a standard optimization.  The standard specificly permits this and specifies in what situations RVO is allowed (clause 12.8 from memory).  All production compilers that I am aware of implement RVO in the situations specified in the standard, so you can count on it.

Comment: @Mortennobel: Yes, RVO is a compiler optimization. The only way to update an existing object is to use an output parameter (e.g. pass by reference) as you figured out in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To update an existing variable you can use an out parameter:

```
// out parameter version
void cross(const Vec3 &b, Vec3& res){
    float ax = p[0], ay = p[1], az = p[2],
        bx = b.p[0], by = b.p[1], bz = b.p[2];
    res.p[0] = ay * bz - az * by;
    res.p[1] = az * bx - ax * bz;
    res.p[2] = ax * by - ay * bx;
    return res;
}
```

RVO will elide the constructor when the return value version is used as an initializer (**but not when assigning to an existing object**):

```
// return value version (RVO)
Vec3 cross(const Vec3& b)
{
    Vec3 t; cross(b, t); return t;
}
```

Also you could offer a mutator of the result object:

```
// assignment version
void set_cross(const Vec3& a, const Vec3& b)
{
    a.cross(b,*this);
}
```

All three member functions can efficiently coexist and reuse each others code as shown.

Comment: But isn't it possible to do (efficiently) without using out-parameters?

Comment: @Mortennobel: Of course! RVO optimization is in all modern compilers.

Comment: No it isn't.  The function needs to know where the result object is so that it can put its data there.

Comment: @Gonmator: RVO only works when the return value initializes a new object, not when assigning the result to an existing object.

Comment: @user1131467: I means in `cross()` member function, not `set_cross()`. What problem are in create object `t`, modify it and then return it?

Comment: @Gonmator: A new temporary object is created and then assigned to the existing object.  This is less efficient then using the target object directly without creating a temporary.  RVO does not help in this situation, only an out parameter can help (whether as a named out parameter (`cross(b, res)`) or as the implicit object parameter (`set_cross`) ).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question and I can only contribute little since the present answers cover the important points but I want to lead your attention towards the downsides of the heap-based design you've chosen.

#### 3d-Vector seldom comes alone.

It is of course a trade-off depending on the number of moves you'll have to make and the number of operations you perform on the vectors.

If you only use some single vectors and do a lot of copy/move stuff you can stick to your heap-base design.
But if you have several vectors (in a vector, or array for example) and you want to operate on them, I'd recommed you to not do heap allocations if you are worried about performance.

```
std::vector<Vec3> a(20);
class con_Vec3 { double x, y, z; };
std::vector<con_Vec3> b(20);
```

The vector `a` will maintain a contiguous block of pointers to float where the float values in turn will reside somewhere else in memory which means your values are actually scattered in memory.
Vector `b` in contrast will contain a contiguous block of 60 `double`s, all in one place.

The cost of moving such a `std::vector` will be equal for both cases (quasi a swap each) but if you copy them, the heap-based solution will be slower, since 21 allocations and 20 copies will take place, whereas in the non-heap solution there is one allocation and 20 copies covering the whole vector.

Comment: Also CPU cache hits may increase processing of loop calculations on `con_Vec3` (as opposed to the almost certain cache miss each time you access the heap allocated data of different elements of `a`).